# Non-const implicit "converting" constructor

Tags: c++, type-conversion, tuples, implicit-conversion

Hi guys I'm working on a messaging system where there are 3 types: Streams (memory), Taps (const view type), Sink(mutable view type). Now constructing a tap from a stream is very easy because it can implicitly convert from a stream to a tap by using the standard const ref conversion constructor. But for sinks I can't seem to figure out how to make it implicitly convert. Implicit conversion is something that saves me a lot of headaches (I'm not trying to get into the whole implicit conversion is evil discussion here) working with tuple and constexpr code here, would it be possible to implicitly construct a sink from a stream, maintaining const correctness?

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct Stream
{
};

template<typename T>
struct Tap
{
    Tap(const Stream<T>& stream)
    {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Sink
{
    Sink(Stream<T>&)
    {}
};



int main()
{
    Stream<float> stream;
    Tap<float> tap = stream;
    //Sink<float> sink = stream;

    std::tuple<Stream<float>, Stream<int>> streams;
    std::tuple<Tap<float>, Tap<int>> taps = streams;
    //std::tuple<Sink<float>, Sink<int>> sinks = streams;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fails because tuple needs to use its converting constructor for the sinks variable.

```
constexpr tuple(const tuple<_U1, _U2>& __in)
```

However, this fails because it adds const qualification onto the streams which then means they cannot be used with the constructor of the Sink class.  For this to work then std::tuple would need a converting constructor that did not add const qualification, i.e.

```
constexpr tuple(tuple<_U1, _U2>& __in)
```

Or you would need to pass it through the equivalent move constructor as such as this gotbolt example show: https://godbolt.org/z/woF__K

Do you need to copy here, would moving suffice?